# Run multiple ASP.Net Core application within the same Process as windows services

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, windows-services

Following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?tabs=aspnetcore2x) tutorial, i was able to deploy an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application as a windows service. This will create a dedicated process to run the service. I was trying next, in vain though, to deploy multiple ASP.NET Core 2.0 apps as windows services but all within the same process. This looked straight forward when i run into this blog [posts](https://devjeremy.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/running-multiple-windows-services-in-a-single-process/) but unfortunately i didn't find a way to make this work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want to deploy them with a single process? Or you want all the service to run under a single process? And why?

Comment: To run under the same process. This is all related to enhancing performance. These services are meant to run together

Comment: How do you think this is going to enhance performance? People often do things to enhance performance without verifying that the think they're trying to speed up is not going to have all that much impact.

Comment: Have lots of services that are deployed as micro-services using a micro-service orchestrator and for a specific scenario we cannot run them as such. We need instead to run them as windows services with IIS running as a reverse proxy. Ideally I want to create multiple processes and with each process i have multiple services running. Does this make sense to you ?

Comment: None of what you said really seems to relate to speed. Why do you think that running them in the same process is going to speed things up?

Comment: running 5 processes vs running 20 will have an impact on you memory footprint and thus your performance,  a process is an expensive entity in windows. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2005/09/09/shared-services/

Comment: That just proves my point. Did you see when that article was written? 2005! Memory is cheap. And unless your processes are designed to really take advantage of having more memory available, then hyper optimizing your memory usage isn't going to do you any good. Most applications only need a finite amout of memory. Having more won't be a magic speed boost. The overhead of separate processes is only going to save you a miniscule amount of memory anyways. If you're having perf problems, find out what the bottlenecks are and fix those. Don't take random guesses at how to speed things up.

Comment: For example, are you caching data? Are you making redundant database, disk, or network calls? Do you have a memory leak? Taking advantage of parallel and/or async processing? Can your application scale to multiple servers and sit behind a load balancer,  or have competing consumers for a message queue?

Comment: You have valid points Thx. We observe all these in our application design. However, I thought that is quite inefficient to have to deploy say 100 processes as windows services vs say 10, or probably if it boils down to this, windows service isn't necessarily the right deployment model and I should just use IIS instead.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with Windows services. The choice between that and IIS will likely depend on the nature of the application. If end users will directly be hitting endpoints then you likely should host in IIS. But as a supporting service that other services talk to, Windows services should be just fine.

Comment: Going back to your original question, if each is a separate ASP.NET Core app, no, there's no way to combine them all into one process. An ASP.NET Core app is inherently just a console app, which will always have it's own process. However, you can potentially use `IHostedService` to house multiple microservices within one ASP.NET Core app. That's a different story.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thx for your input, is using IHostService any different from deploying each micro-service into a virtual directory within the same IIS deployment ?

Comment: Entirely. You'd basically have to re-architect each microservice. An IHostedService is pretty simplistic. It has startup and shutdown and then simply executes some task in between. That task could be something simplistic like checking for database changes to update cache, or potentially as complex as actually listening for and responding to requests. However, you have to work it into a different infrastructure than just deploying a Core app and calling it a day. It's somewhat similar to the concepts of Azure Functions or AWS Lambdas

Comment: @ChrisPratt Great Thx i will defintely check it out. Will the encapsulating Asp.Net Core app along with the micro-services run within the same process ?